# SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, toggle

If I click once link ,there is no problem but after that when I click another link with same grid my buttons are not working with internet explorer and i am gettig this error SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference.

**My Code behind :**

```
<a href=""javascript:;"" onclick=""toogleUserDetailNew(this.id,'../../FRP/Administration/UserDetails.aspx?id=" & item.ExternalDiplomaticUserID & "&rowid=" & iCount & "' )"" id=""" & iCount & ""></a>
```

**My javascript function**

```
function toogleUserDetailNew(id,pageurl) {
    //var pageurl = '../../FRP/Administration/UserDetails.aspx?id=' + id +'&rowid='+ id +'';
    var dStatus = $('.content_details').length;
    rowId = id;
    if (dStatus > 0) {

        var oStatus = $('#row' + id).find('.content_details').length;
        if (oStatus > 0) {

            $('#row' + id + ' .content_details').slideUp(450, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {

                $('#row' + id + ' .content_details').remove();

            });

        } else {
            $('.content_details').slideUp(450, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {

                $('.content_details').remove();

                getDetailPage(pageurl, showUserDetail);
            });
            //getHTML('user-detail', showUserDetail);
        }


    } else {

        rowId = id;
        getDetailPage(pageurl, showUserDetail);
        //getHTML('user-detail', showUserDetail);

    }

}
```

Comment: So where are you setting a value?

Comment: And on which line do you get that?

Comment: here <a href=""javascript:;"" onclick=""toogleUserDetailNew(this.id,'../../FRP/Administration/UserDetails.aspx?id=" & item.ExternalDiplomaticUserID & "&rowid=" & iCount & "' )"" id=""" & iCount & ""></a>

Comment: function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
 7   if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
  8      theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
   9     theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    10    theForm.submit();
    }
}